# dropdownlist dynamic select

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Trying to select a dropdownlist item based on a value

```
 Dim basedate As Date
    basedate = "12/30/1899"
    Label26.Text = basedate.AddDays(y)
    ddate.SelectedIndex = ddate.Items.IndexOf(ddate.Items.FindByValue(Label26.Text))
```

Comment: Looks correct. Are you sure there's a item in the dropdownlist with the correct value

Comment: oops the problem is they are dates and one is 3/24/2011 and the other 03/24/2011

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not do:

```
ddate.SelectedValue = Label26.Text;
```

instead a the issue may be an equal comparison of the ListItem class...  This will also establish the SelectedIndex property to the correct value too.

HTH.